# texmathp in isearch-filter-predicate breaks query-replace's match highlighting

Tags: latex, isearch, query-replace, isearch-filter-predicate

I tried to use [`texmathp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=blob;f=texmathp.el;hb=HEAD) with `iserch-filter-predicate` to let `query-replace` function skipping maths in my `LaTeX` code.

I wrote this code:

```el
(defun skip-math (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is a LaTeX maths environment or in in-line maths."
  (require 'texmathp)
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos  beg))
      (while (< pos end)
        (when (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
        (setq pos  (1+ pos))))
    t))

(defmacro with-query-replace-skip-math (&rest body)
  "Makes search-* and query-seplace* commands in BODY skip LaTeX maths strings."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let ((isearch-filter-predicate 'skip-math)) 
     ,@body))


(defun foo-to-bar ()
  (interactive)
  (with-query-replace-skip-math
      (query-replace-regexp "foo" 
                "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

I tested on:

```latex
%% bar foo

foo

\begin{equation}
foo
\end{equation}

foo $ foo $

bar $$ foo $$ foo

\begin{displaymath}
foo
\end{displaymath}

%% foo

bar %% foo bar foo
```

It works but the `query-replace` match highlighting is broken:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't show `skip-math-and-comments`. You show only `skip-math`.

Comment: `texmathp` doesn't seem to depend on a position (doesn't accept one as arg). What's the point of iterating from `beg` to `end` in that case? Do you perhaps need to move to `pos`? (But you say it works, other than the highlighting problem.)

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you use a different predicate or is this somehow specific to using `texmathp`?

Comment: @Drew, sorry is a typo.

Comment: Googling for `texmathp`... Its doc string says *"Determine if point is inside (La)TeX math mode."* So it sounds like your filter predicate needs to *move point* to each position `pos`, to test that position. E.g., `(goto-char (setq pos...))`.

Comment: I don't see a highlighting problem, for example, when I use this in place of your `while` loop: 
`(save-excursion
 (while (< pos end)
          (when (looking-at-p "re") (throw 'skip-region nil))
          (goto-char (setq pos  (1+ pos)))))`. That skips matches containing `re`, and only the remaining matches are treated as such and highlighted.

Comment: @Drew I tried `(save-excursion
 (goto-char pos)
 (while (< pos end)
   (when (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
   (goto-char (setq pos  (1+ pos)))))`. It also works but breaks the highlighting yet.

Comment: Try a predicate without `texmathp`, to see if you have the same problem with highlighting. If you do not then try `debug-on-entry `texmathp` (after loading the source, not *.elc) file.

Comment: @Drew I solved with `save-match-data`. See the solution below. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for posting the answer. You can accept your own answer. That makes it clear to other readers what the answer is. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `texmathp` function alters the `match-data` so I solved wrapping the `while` loop in my function (modified following Drew's suggestions) with the `save-match-data` macro:

```el
(defun skip-math (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is a LaTeX maths environment or in in-line maths."
  (require 'texmathp)
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos  beg))      
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (when (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos  (1+ pos)))))
        t))))

(defun foo-to-bar ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((isearch-filter-predicate 'skip-math))
    (query-replace-regexp "foo" 
                          "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

[image]